# Error en proceso almacenado de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

estoy diseñando una base de datos de un sitio web de agenda médica. Hice una tabla Consultas en donde se almacenan los datos de los reportes de las consultas, pero a la hora de hacer el siguiente proceso almacenado me aparece un error:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertConsulta;
DELIMITER &&
CREATE PROCEDURE insertConsulta( 
    _nombrePaciente VARCHAR(70),
    _nombreMedico VARCHAR(70),
    _emailPaciente VARCHAR(50),
    _cedulaProfesional VARCHAR(14),
    _sintomas VARCHAR(255),
    _diagnostico VARCHAR(255),
    _tratamiento VARCHAR(255),
    _fechaAgendada DATE,
    _horaAgendada TIME,
    _fechaConsulta DATE,
    _horaConsulta TIME,
    _precio FLOAT  
)
BEGIN
SET @idCita = (SELECT ci.ID_Cita FROM Cita ci INNER JOIN Usuario us ON 
us.ID_Usuario = ci.ID_Usuario INNER JOIN Medicos me ON me.ID_Medico = 
ci.ID_Medico WHERE us.nombre = _nombrePaciente AND me.nombre = _nombreMedico 
AND _fechaAgendada = fecha_citaAgendada AND _horaAgendada = 
hora_citaAgendada);
SET @idUsuario = (SELECT ID_Usuario FROM Cita WHERE ID_Cita = @idCita);
SET @idMedico = (SELECT ID_Medico FROM Cita WHERE ID_Cita = @idCita);
IF(COUNT(@idCita ) = 1) THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Consultas(
            ID_Cita, 
            ID_Usuario,
            ID_Medico,
            sintomas,
            diagnostico, 
            tratamiento, 
            fecha_consulta,
            tipoConsulta,
            precio,
            fecha_agendada
        )
        VALUES(
            @idCita,
            @idUsuario,
            @idMedico,
            _sintomas,
            _diagnostico,
            _tratamiento,
            CONCAT(_fechaConsulta,' ',_horaConsulta),
            0,
            _precio,
            CONCAT(_fechaAgendada,' ',_horaAgendada)
        );
    END;
ELSEIF(COUNT(@idCita) = 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Consultas(
            ID_Cita, 
            ID_Usuario,
            ID_Medico,
            sintomas,
            diagnostico, 
            tratamiento, 
            fecha_consulta,
            tipoConsulta,
            precio,
            fecha_agendada
        )
        VALUES(
            NULL,
            (SELECT ID_Usuario FROM Usuario us WHERE us.nombre = _nombrePaciente AND _emailPaciente = us.email),
            (SELECT ID_Medico FROM Medicos me WHERE me.nombre = _nombreMedico AND _cedulaProfesional = me.cedulaProfesional),
            _sintomas,
            _diagnostico,
            _tratamiento,
            CONCAT(_fechaConsulta,' ',_horaConsulta),
            1,
            _precio,
            CONCAT(_fechaAgendada,' ',_horaAgendada)
        );
    END;
END IF;
END&&
DELIMITER ;
```

El error que me aparece es este:

Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Mi duda principalmente surge porque ni siquiera estoy utilizando un Group By ni nada similar he investigado un poco y en todos los códigos que he visto que tenían el mismo error siempre usaban la funcion Group By.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuántas filas se supone que debe devolver cada una de tus consultas?  Es que no encuentro la lógica que estás implementando. Por ejemplo, asignas a la variable `@idCita` un resultado desde un `SELECT` y luego intentas hacer un `COUNT` de esa variable con `IF(COUNT(@idCita ) = 1) THEN` ¿? Realmente no entiendo mucho por qué haces eso.

Comment: La variable @idCita debe retornar 1 o 0, dependiendo de si encuentra el ID en el SELECT o no. Y de ahí aplica una u otra condición. Esa es la explicación pero no tiene que ver con el error ya que si me había ayer pero estaba incompleto, le faltaba funcionalidad y ahora que se la agregue me marca ese error que menciono.

Comment: `COUNT()` es una función de agregación y creo que el error se debe precisamente a esto: `IF(COUNT(@idCita ) = 1) THEN` por eso mi pregunta. Deberías recoger el conteo en `@idCita`  y luego usarla para comparar. Algo así: **`SET @idCita = (SELECT COUNT(ci.ID_Cita) FROM Cita ci ...`** y luego **`IF(@idCita = 1) THEN ...`**  y lo mismo en el `ELSE` poniendo **`ELSEIF(@idCita = 0) THEN ...`**